# mailing system not working in bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

Installed Bugzilla and its working fine with out email configuration. Created hmailserver for local mail system and configured in outlook. It is also working fine with outlook.

Now I have to configure this local mail server in bugzilla. I did some steps but not working, see the below step what i did.

```
--> Administration - Parameters - Required Settings - given urlbase as of my ip address
--> Administration - Parameters - Email - 
                         mail_delivery_method = smtp
                         mailfrom = given on local mail id (it is working in outlook)
                         smtpserver = my ip address
```

with this configuration smtpserver is connecting but while creating new bug or update new bug it is trying to send mail and giving below error

```
There was an error sending mail from 'mailid' to 'mailid': Can't send data
```

on smtp_debug and i got following errors.

```
[error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::bootstrap redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 207.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::CLONE redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::fastcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::getcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::abs_path redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::getdcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::canonpath redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_canonpath redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::catdir redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_catdir redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::catfile redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:09 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_catfile redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::bootstrap redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 207.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::CLONE redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::fastcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::getcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::abs_path redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::getdcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::canonpath redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_canonpath redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::catdir redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_catdir redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::catfile redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:20 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_catfile redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/post_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::bootstrap redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 207.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::CLONE redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::fastcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::getcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::abs_path redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine Cwd::getdcwd redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::canonpath redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_canonpath redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::catdir redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_catdir redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::catfile redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Subroutine File::Spec::Unix::_fn_catfile redefined at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 214.\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(2.32), referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.30), referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.68), referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.33), referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.34), referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.33), referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 220 Internet-Lap_1 ESMTP, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)>>> EHLO 192.168.1.3\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 250-Internet-Lap_1, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 250-SIZE 20480000, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 250 AUTH LOGIN, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)>>> MAIL FROM:<srikanth@urslocal.com>\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 250 OK, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)>>> RCPT TO:<srikanth@urslocal.com>\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 530 SMTP authentication is required., referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)>>> DATA\r, referer: http://192.168.1.3/enter_bug.cgi
[Fri Sep 26 11:43:27 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x4f4f6a8)<<< 503 Must have sender and recipient first., referer:
```

Could you tell me what is wrong in my configuration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the smtp_debug param and looking in your web server's error log.

Does your mailserver require a username and password? If so, you have to tell Bugzilla it.

Can your Bugzilla machine ping the mailserver?

Comment: Yes I on the smtp_debug param and Just now I updated my question by add log file errors. Even i dont have smtp server authentications also.

Comment: And one more my bugzilla and mailserver is same both in same machine

Comment: Your log says "SMTP authentication is required". So it seems like your mailserver _does_ require authentication.

It is much easier to use an existing mail server rather than set up a new one on your Bugzilla machine. Does your company not have an internal mailserver you can use, which you can get an SMTP username and password for?

Comment: But while configure in outlook also i did not given any credentials for SMTP, it works fine in outlook. Even I only configured local mail server and I did not given any authentication for SMTP.